# What rendering hints shall I use to get the map smoother?

Tags: geotools, rendering

I would like to render my maps a bit smoother. I use the shape file viewer example from GeoTools. And I would like to render it more like QGIS.

Geotools origianally:
[image]

QGIS:
[image]

GeoTools and VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON:
[image]

This is what I added in JMapPane.doSetRenderer:

```
if(!MapView.SimpleRenderer) {
    hints.put("optimizedDataLoadingEnabled", true); 
    newRenderer.setRendererHints(hints);
    RenderingHints newHints= new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    newRenderer.setJava2DHints(newHints);
}
else {
    RenderingHints newHints= new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIASING_OFF);
    newRenderer.setJava2DHints(newHints);
}
```

I think Geotools VALUE_ANTIALIASING_ON gives a to fat 1 pixel line compared to QGIS.
What hints shall I use to get it more like QGIS?

Comment: are the styles the same? do you have any slightly larger images?

Comment: The style is the same, I've updated the images (screen shots from each application)

Comment: I can't see any difference between the geotools and qgis images, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: I can't see any difference between the geotools and qgis images, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: The border line (black) when using Geotools VALUE_ANTIALIASING_ON is wider than in QGIS. Line width is set to 1 in all the pictures. It looks at least to "heavy" out for beeing 1 pixel wide. Is there not any differens between the pictures in your browser?

Comment: I was ignoring the anti-alias as it is usually only used for text rather than lines. I can't tell the difference between the top two pictures